# Enumerate list with filter criteria

Tags: c#, .net, linq, finance

Given the following `CreditCard` object, how would you get a count of unexpired credit cards? What are the pros/cons of using each method? Or is there a better/optimal way?

```
public class CreditCard
{
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public int Month { get; set; }
    public int Day { get; set; }
}
public class User
{
    public User()
    {
        CreditCards = new List<CreditCard>();
    }

    public List<CreditCard> CreditCards { get; set; }

    public int NumberOfCreditCards
    {
        get
        {
            int count = 0;
            DateTime localDate = DateTime.Now;
            foreach (CreditCard creditCard in CreditCards)
            {
                DateTime expDate = new DateTime(creditCard.Year, creditCard.Month, creditCard.Day);
                if (DateTime.Compare(expDate, localDate) > 0)
                {
                    count++;
                }
            }

            return count;
        }
    }
}
```

Is LINQ a better performer?

```
public int NumberOfCreditCards
{
    get
    {
        DateTime localDate = DateTime.Now;
        return CreditCards.Select(creditCard => new DateTime(creditCard.Year, creditCard.Month, creditCard.Day))
            .Count(expDate => DateTime.Compare(expDate, localDate) > 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I will assume that the `CreditCard` class is set in stone, otherwise I probably would store a `DateTime` in it and calculate `Year`, `Month` and `Day` properties based on that value. Or at least add a separate method or property that'd return a `DateTime`.

With that said, first of all, I wouldn't use `DateTime.Compare` since there're documented operators for comparing `DateTime`s (see further [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059497/how-to-compare-datetime-in-c)). Using them is certainely more readable, because reading `DateTime.Compare(d1, d2) > 0` makes one (at least me) lag for a moment to realize what exactly it means. Personally I like the LINQ variant much more than the loop one, but I don't think that the intermediate `Select` statement is necessary, because it contains such trivial logic. I think that the most readable variant, that I'd probably put into production code, looks like this:

```
public int NumberOfCreditCards
{
    get
    {
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
        return CreditCards
            .Count(card => new DateTime(card.Year, card.Month, card.Day) > now);
    }
}
```

More things that I'd change:

- It's probably debatable, but I feel that making `NumberOfCreditCards` a method and renaming it into something more transparent like `GetNumberOfActiveCreditCards` would make the code cleaner. It depends on current time and doesn't seem (at least to me) to be a logical atribute of the `User` type (official [guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms229054(v=vs.100).aspx)).
- You should consider defining the public `CreditCards` property as `IReadOnlyCollection<CreditCard>`. A `List` should be exposed only when you expect the client code to modify your collection, otherwise it's better to use a restrictive interface. And `IReadOnlyCollection` is better than `IEnumerable` because it clearly states that the property returns a collection that won't be enumerated at runtime (e.g. that it's not a method with `yield return;`). It's quite a common practice and the reasoning is written by the TS [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24880268/ienumerable-vs-ireadonlycollection-vs-readonlycollection-for-exposing-a-list-mem). But again, this topic is debatable.

Answer (score 3):

I'd add two extension methods on the CreditCard class like so:

```
public static DateTime ExpiryDate(this CreditCard creditCard)
{
   return new DateTime(Year, Month, Day);
}

public static bool IsActive(this CreditCard creditCard, DateTime effectiveDate = null)
{
   if (effectiveDate == null)
       effectiveDate = DateTime.now;
   return ExpiryDate() > effectiveDate;
}
```

You can then get all the active cards (and their count) as follows:

```
var activeCardCount = CreditCards.Count(card => card.IsActive());
var activeCardList = CreditCards.Where(card => card.IsActive());
```

More on Extension methods [here](http://www.planetofcoders.com/c-extension-methods/).

I added the optional `effectiveDate` parameter because I think it's likely you might want to see whose card is still active/not expired next month at some point.

Comment: Personally I'd prefer this method. But you don't need to pass in the default value for the optional parameter; it's optional. Also I might prefer `IsActive` if it's a method.

Comment: @moarboilerplate Thanks for the feedback! I forgot to remove the `null` after I added the optional, and `IsActive` is definitely better. I keep having troubles switching from Ruby conventions where you can have methods like `active?`.

Answer (score 2):

Linq is never more performant than well written non-Linq code because there's an overhead with `expressions`. *But*, [is Linq fast enough?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3769989/should-linq-be-avoided-because-its-slow)

Yes it is. While Linq might not be faster, it is most definitively clearer in your case. The other answers already point out how to deal with the Linq.

As @Andrey pointed out, having another property to check the expired credit cards is a very good idea.

I have another concern. Your `CreditCards` property is a public setter and exposes `List`.

Firstly, a collection should (almost) *never* have a public setter. You want to initialize your list once, in your constructor. Adding/removing/modifying elements within the list can be done even if the setter is private.

Secondly, you shouldn't expose `List`. The `List` is an [implementation detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777719/what-is-the-definition-of-an-implementation-detail). You should expose an interface like `ICollection` if you want to be able to add/remove from your list or expose `IEnumerable` if you want people to have a read-only access to your collection.

```
public class User
{
    public User()
    {
        CreditCards = new List<CreditCard>();
    }

    public ICollection<CreditCard> CreditCards { get; private set; }

    //etc..
}
```